# Are you allowed to ask about general principles of a certain type of math?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

So, if I ask a question like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789858/radical-equation), but what I want to know the general principles of solving such equations, where would I ask? Are those types of questions allowed?

A question of that sort would be something like:

> What are the general ways to solve radical equations similar to $\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x-1}-\sqrt{x^2 -1}=x$? Are there just a few known ways to solve them? How do you know the best way to solve such questions?

Comment: The ([tag:problem-solving]) tag comes to mind. If you read [the tag description](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/problem-solving/info), it says: *"Use this tag when you want to determine the thinking that is needed to solve a certain type of problem, as opposed to looking for a specific answer to a question."* (There used to be somewhat similar tag (proof-strategy), but it has been removed, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21843) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21967).

Comment: Related older question: [Can I ask about a basic solving strategy for specific kinds of math tasks?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/can-i-ask-about-a-basic-solving-strategy-for-specific-kinds-of-math-tasks)

Comment: Just asking, would my sample question be allowed on the math.stackexchange site?

Comment: If I were you, I would first try to search whether such question was not asked before. Maybe you can browse questions in the tag ([tag:radicals]) might be reasonable. Perhaps you can try to search some reasonable keywords, like [solving](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bradicals%5D+solving) or [strategy](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bradicals%5D+strategy). If you do not find it, go ahead and ask. It is still possible that it might get closed as too broad. But it is also possible that it will be well received.

Comment: Ok, thanks; I'll try that